# Consecutive ajax requests aborts first request

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, spring-mvc

My application runs on jQuery and Spring MVC.

I have a grid which contains a hyperlink on reference number which is unique. 
On clicking reference number, an ajax request is sent to the spring controller with reference number as the request parameter.

When an user clicks on two reference number quickly, two ajax requests are submitted to the server  which results in the first request being aborted with status code 0 and second request is processed successfully.
The same happens for extreme slow network also.

When user clicks on two reference number after a certain interval, both the requests are processed successfully.

Can anyone please explain why the first request among the two gets aborted in slow network?

Below is the spring controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/details/{ReferenceNo}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getDetails(@PathVariable String ReferenceNo,ModelMap map) {
       //server side stuffs
}
```

The client side code:

```
var $target = jQuery(e.target);
var href = application_path + $target.attr('href');
$.ajax({
 url:href,
 type:GET,
 success:function(content){
  //open the details
 }
});
```

Comment: pretty hard to say without seeing some client side code.  There is an abort method for xhr requests that can be triggered to handle ajax requests in the manner you're describing.

Comment: @Rooster: As per the client side code, there is no xhr.abort() calls made

Comment: What browser are you testing in?  Have you tried in a different browser?

Comment: Also, since you mention slow links, is it possible the ajax call is timing out?  Can you add an error handler to the call and check to see if it is?